# Is it possible to add strings to the special arguments?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following Shell code and whenever I try to execute it, it never works.

```
user$ ./test.sh hello
user$ hello world
```

How do I get rid of the " " whitespace between 'hello world'? Here my code:

```
get_input=$1
get_output="world"
echo $get_input$get_output
```

**Edit:** Above statement works, I made a silly mistake on my variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
get_input=$1
get_output="world"
echo "$get_input$get_output"
```

It works for me..

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out why mines put a space in-between. In-fact I got the whole thing wrong, it wasn't actually the above statement. One of my variable has a command and for some reason that command is always putting white space in front of my string.